Отключить автоматический pipeline при git push на Gitlab
Определённых пользователей недавно добавили в проект на Gitlab. И при git push у них автоматически запускается pipeline. Даже если пушат в новые ветки, а не в main. В чём может быть причина и как это отключить? Файл .gitlab-ci.yml у пользователей локально не менялся.
Содержание файла .gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine:latest
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache openssh-client sshpass git
    - if [ -z "$SERVER_IP" ] || [ -z "$SERVER_PASSWORD" ] || [ -z "$SERVER_USERNAME" ] || [ -z "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" ]; then echo "Server credentials are not set"; exit 1; fi
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - ssh-keyscan $SERVER_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - ssh -T git@gitlab.com
    - sshpass -p "$SERVER_PASSWORD" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USERNAME@$SERVER_IP "cd /home/dev/ecomvue-backend && git pull origin main && docker compose up --build -d"
  only:
    - main

Пробовали создавать новые ветки и делать git push в них, pipeline всё равно создаётся.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2496
